# Why must physics (empirical measurement) be consistent?

Tags: reality

In [this TEDx talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Chfoo9NBEow), Physicist and Nobel Laureate George Smoot claims (around 19:00) that inconsistency in measurements of the universe imply either that our universe is not *real*, that is, that we live in a simulated reality, or that or ability to measure the universe is flawed.

This seems to imply that Smoot is making the presumption that the *real* universe must be consistent. Why should we expect that measurements in a real universe must be consistent?

Comment: I can't watch the video right now, so I can't use his words for an answer, but "make it likely" does not mean he's making the presumption that the real universe is consistent.  Likelihood is a very tricky statistical concept, but it is reasonable to say "If we observe artifacts in measurement that are consistent with a simulation, it is reasonable to assume the likelihood of the universe being a simulation increases."

Comment: @CortAmmon I understand what you mean about "likelihood", thank you for bringing that to my attention. Smoot says "Apparently we have contradictions. Is that because we aren't good at resolving things, or because we're in a simulation?" He seems to overlook the case that reality is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

> This seems to imply that Smoot is making the presumption that the real universe must be consistent.

The underlying assumption that Smoot is making here is that there is a single [Theory of Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_everything) that explains the whole universe and unifies all science. Alternatively this view can be expressed as the idea that all sciences will ultimately be reduced to fundamental physics (in the way that chemistry was reduced to quantum mechanics or that genetics was reduced to molecular biology thanks to the discovery of DNA).

So then to answer the question of whether:

> Why should we expect that measurements in a real universe must be consistent?

Really comes down to arguments for or against a unified Theory of Everything. If there is a ToE explaining the whole universe, then we should expect all of our measurements to be consistent. If there is no ToE, then there is no reasons why different scientific theories - having different domains of application - need to be consistent with each other. There is a lot to debate in this question, but here are a couple of considerations:

- The [materialism/dualism/idealism debate](http://www.jimpryor.net/teaching/courses/intro/notes/dualism.html): A unifying Theory of Everything presumes a purely physical universe. If there are non-physical and mental aspects to our universe then presumably a physical theory of everything can never account for the non physical.
- The reductionism vs [emergentism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties-emergent/) debate: Emergentists argue that some physical phenomena can't be reduced to other physical phenomena no matter how hard we try. Examples are theories of the mind which claim that the mind is physical (no souls or special mind substance) but that psychology can't be reduced to neuroscience nonetheless. More interestingly some physics, results are seen as arguments against reductionism even in physics ([see this paper for example](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0151)).

A really interesting book I read on the topic is ["A Tear at the Edge of Creation"](http://www.npr.org/books/titles/163981302/a-tear-at-the-edge-of-creation-a-radical-new-vision-for-life-in-an-imperfect-uni), by physicist Marcelo Gleiser. In it he argues that recent discoveries (including the frequent inconsistencies in measurement that Smoot talks about) indicate that a Theory of Everything is unlikely. He also argues that there *is no reason* for us to expect such a theory in the first place, and that the only reason people have expected such a theory is a holdover from monotheistic religious beliefs. He argues that the idea of single God who created the universe is so deeply ingrained in Western culture, that even those who don't believe in God still work with the assumption that a single set of fundamental laws must govern the universe, even though empirical evidence points in the other direction.

Comment: How does my CPU, Windows, and Browser give rise to this Comment? What if you are using an identical PC? Would you post the same comment here? Physicalist / Materialist idea is so silly as to be nonsensical. All the other theories are as well. Would my identical twin post this comment? Someone who went to the same school? Some questions are simply not worth entertaining. TOE is silly. What does it do for us? Does the cost of food go down? Are people happier for having it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think George Smoot is arguing that "the real Universe must be consistent".

He's certainly not arguing in a Theory of Everything sense; if he was talking about theory, he would have said it differently.

He's discussing whether *measurements* must (if properly done) be consistent: If you measure some single quantity multiple times and/or in multiple ways, all done properly, "consistency" means you get the same result each time.

Physicists tend to believe that there really is a there there:  That the Universe is in some sense "real" and exists whether we understand it or not, that it operates/behaves/acts on it's own.  If the Universe really is a thing, then that thing has to be consistent with itself:  there just the one of it, and our measurements are looking at the same thing over and over.

That sounds so obvious that it's hard to say clearly, so let's consider a different case: They Universe is just some values stored in a Really Big Computer that's doing a simulation.  Well, in that case, maybe there isn't a single value to a measurement, because the simulation isn't exact, or only gets more exact as time goes on, or values get updated as the simulation works along.   Then maybe measuring the same thing multiple times will get you different values.

Comment: +1 However, if we are in a simulation shouldn't we be able to find the theory of everything which would be the program that is running the simulation?  Admittedly there may be random number generators involved or imprecision at the last decimal place.  I don't think we are in a simulation. I am just pursuing the idea to see where it leads.

Comment: When humans write simulations, they tend to make arbitrary choices about level of detail: movie CGI puts a lot of cycles into the foreground but little in the background; macroeconomic simulations don’t simulate the details of every aspect of the economy; Grand Theft Auto doesn’t bother to simulate an entire planet. Although these choices are the ‘rules’ of the simulation, they come from outside it: how much time and talent the Grand Simulator had, what the goal is, etc. In such a case, the occupants of the simulation might never have the information to reason those out.